# Making an exception for characters such as '<= $example ?>' in the HAML pre-processor?

Tags: php, html, haml, preprocessor

is it possible to make the HAML pre-proccessor ignore for I.E. `<?= $test ?>` and just print it out as it is? To then turn the HTML file into a PHP file to be used as a template.

Answer (score 0):

If using code in page with `.html` extension then it will directly shown the `PHP` code as it is.

But for `.php` file, [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) can be used. For example:

```
echo htmlentities('<?= $test ?>');
```